# Load key "privkey.ppk" invalid format

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ubuntu-18.04

**What have I done:**
I'm trying to connect to my remote server with private key with

```
ssh -i privkey.ppk root@ip
```

But it's returning an error.
**Error message:**

```
Load key "privkey.ppk": invalid format
root@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
```

**Expected result:**
I should be able to login into my remote server with ssh key.

**Key file content:**

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: rsa-key-20181019
Public-Lines: 6
some lines
Private-Lines: 14
some lines
Private-MAC: some letters
```

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04

(**p.s:**

1. I'm using the same key in putty, termius to login into my remote server and its working fine
2. Ansible ping cmd also returning the same result)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My PPK was in putty PPK format I had to convert into OpenSSH format.
I converted .ppk to OpenSSH using this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/232365), now I'm able to connect.

```
puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O public-openssh -o id_dsa.pub
```

Comment: For me, i was convert it to "pem" format instead of "pub" format and it's work.
`puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O private-openssh -o id_dsa.pem`. Hope it's help some one.

Answer (score 33):

This key is generated by PuTTYgen software. To use it in linux you should start PuTTYgen, load the key (File->Load private key) and then export it as OpenSSH key ( Conversions->Export OpenSSH key)

Comment: Can it be done on a Macbook?

Comment: @MemphisMeng, you have `ssh` client on MacOS, why you will need Putty?

Comment: Never mind, it was just a silly question after I figured that I should ask for the passphrase.